# htaccess 301 redirect joomla URLs with multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I'm trying to redirect this URL:

https://www.sendmoneypacific.org/index.php?option=com_countries&view=details&Itemid=165&lang=en

to this URL:

https://www.sendmoneypacific.org/pacific-communities/solomon-islands.html

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_countries&view=details&Itemid=165&lang=en$
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ https://www.sendmoneypacific.org/pacific-communities/solomon-islands.html? [R=301,L]
```

and:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_countries&amp;view=details&amp;Itemid=165&amp;lang=en$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sendmoneypacific.org/pacific-communities/solomon-islands.html? [R=301,L]
```

But neither work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Leanne, why aren't you posting on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange?  Also, why not ask to have your two accounts merged?  I hope to see you JoomlaDay in Melbourne next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -

```
## https://www.sendmoneypacific.org/index.php?option=com_countries&view=details&Itemid=165&lang=en
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option\=com_countries&view\=details&Itemid\=165&lang\=en$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.sendmoneypacific.org/pacific-communities/solomon-islands.html? [R=301,L]
```

If anyone else needs help with this